# Karate Labs issue after upgrade from 0.9.6 to 1.1.0

Tags: java, karate

I'm using a feature to generate public/private key

```
Background:

def keyPairGen =
"""
function() {
var kpg = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2058);
return kpg.genKeyPair();
}
"""
def uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' }
Scenario:

def kid = uuid()
def keyPair = keyPairGen()
def publicKey = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded()
```

I'am using Karate Netty with jar version 1.1.0

And i got this error:

Caused by: com.intuit.karate.KarateException: js failed:

01: keyPairGen().getPublic().getEncoded()
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to public member failed: sun.security.x509.X509Key.getEncoded[Ljava.lang.Object;@796d33eb/invokeVirtual, from public Lookup

com.oracle.truffle.host.HostMethodDesc$SingleMethod$MethodMHImpl.makeMethodHandle(HostMethodDesc.java:352)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostMethodDesc$SingleMethod$MHBase.invokeGuestToHost(HostMethodDesc.java:311)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNode.doInvoke(HostExecuteNode.java:828)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNode.doFixed(HostExecuteNode.java:132)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(HostExecuteNodeGen.java:140)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostExecuteNodeGen.execute(HostExecuteNodeGen.java:95)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostObject.invokeMember(HostObject.java:441)

Comment: I've nothing to add other than a link to the upgrade guide: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide - it can very well be that you ran into an issue that no one else encountered - so either you find a solution on your own, or provide us with a way to replicate. may I remind you that we spent many months asking for feedback on RC releases for 1.0, we have now moved on

Comment: The cause of this error is that Graal VM JS engine can't access the sun.* pakage methods in the jdk.
Since I use the jar in my project which is a mock server based on karate Netty, the java code is written in a js function and thus compiled by Graal.

I will use the karate pom, and I will move the java code into classes. I hope that the java classes will be compiled directly by the jdk and that I won't have this error linked to Graal. what do you think @PeterThomas

Comment: that sounds correct to me. yes if you depend on some wrapper code that is better. if that doesn't work consider importing a library to do RSA / crypto etc